# How to get Bootstrap navbar to display correctly in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, microsoft-edge

I added an extra hyperlink element in the Boostrap navbar. It renders fine in all browsers except Microsoft Edge.

What do I need to change so that it renders correctly in Microsoft Edge as well?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            .theScore {
                color:yellow; 
                float:left;
                padding: 11px 0 0 0;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">                    
                    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">User</a>: 
                        <a class="theScore" href="#">0000000</a>                    
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lol, its simple remove the colon right after the line ,

User: [image]

its highlighted in image